# Array of object - get id for selected user name inside function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, ecmascript-6

```
const user = [
{name:"jonh" ,id:EAD1234},
{name:"peter" ,id:EAD1235},
{name:"matt" ,id:EAD1236},
{name:"henry" ,id:EAD1237},
]
```

I have above mentioned array of object,
I want to get selected user id dynamically based on user selection using es6 and javascript e.g. if i select john i should get EAD1234. and it must suitable on large number of records

I tried using filter method

Comment: Is `filter()` doesn't work for you?

Comment: i need to call it inside submit function where it might iterate over large number of data and it might affect performance

Comment: Then the better choice is to store the data inside a database or cache

Answer (score 2):

No need to filter through the whole array if the id values are unique:

```
function getUserByID(id, users) {
  for (const u of users) {
    if (u.id === id) {
      return u;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

If your data really is exceptionally large and it makes sense to store it on the front-end look into using [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).

---

**Edit**: Someone in the comments somewhere mentioned [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), so you might as well just use the built-in.

```
function getUserByID(id, users) {
  return users.find((u) => u.id === id) || null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data is samll,then just combine `Array.filter()` and `Array.map()` can do it.

If the data is too large,we can store the data into a database such as `mysql` or `redis`,then query it dynamiclly

```js
const user = [
{name:"jonh" ,id:'EAD1234'},
{name:"peter" ,id:'EAD1235'},
{name:"matt" ,id:'EAD1236'},
{name:"henry" ,id:'EAD1237'}
]

let id = 'EAD1234'
let result = user.filter(u => u.id === id).map(u => u.name)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: let id = 'EAD1234' should not be hard coded

Comment: `let id = 'EAD1234'` it will depends on your input

Answer (score 0):

```
const user = [
    {name:"john"  ,id:'EAD1234'},
    {name:"peter" ,id:'EAD1235'},
    {name:"matt"  ,id:'EAD1236'},
    {name:"henry" ,id:'EAD1237'},
];

let userName = "john";
let userId = user.filter(user => user.name === userName)[0].name;
```

Comment: It's better to use `.find()` instead of `.filter()[0]`. `find()` will stop its search as soon as it finds a match, whereas `.filter()` iterates the entire array. By indexing `0` you're ignoring all of the other values `.filter()` potentially found, so that additional work isn't needed. Using `.find()` will help with  performance (especially with large arrays like OP has mentioned they have)